# Regarding dropdown list selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am bit new in asp.net so please forgive me if my question is silly.

Actually I am loading a page(aspx) through `window.open`. Everything thing is going fine window is coming with the requested page.

This page is having two panels in a same row ie. in two td's.

One panel is for showing data from different kind of source and the other one is for different kind of source.
Now my problem is with this dropdowns. In my page m having around 10 dropdowns, 5 is left side and 5 is for right side.

when I am setting the values to these dropdowns for both side ( left column 5 dropdowns with differnt values and rith column 5 dropdowns with different values).

i have two seperate methods for "selected vlues" for these dropdowns for each side.

Now problem is........whichever method i call last........that values are appearing in the both side of dropdowns. though i used different methods for selecting values.

see the code snippet of the pageload calls...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
   // methods for filling all dropdowns-----
   FetchData();  // for first side 
   FetchData_Q2(); // second side                                         
}


private void FetchData() 
{ 
     ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "2"; 
     ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "5"; 
} 

private void FetchData_Q2() 
{ 
     ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "1"; 
     ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "1"; 
}
```

SO here first side(FetchData()) dropdown is also showing the data as like as second side(FetchData_Q2())

HOPE U R GETTING MY PROBLEM.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody will "get" your problem without seeing your code. Showing us the call to functions means absolutely nothing without seeing the functions / markup

Comment: show us your code FetchData() and FetchData_Q2()

Comment: private void FetchData()
    {
        ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "2";
        ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "5";
     }


private void FetchData_Q2()
    {
        ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "1";
        ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "1";
     }

but for both the side values are appearing as like as for second.
the dropdowns are...

Comment: private void FetchData()
    {
        ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "2";
        ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "5";
     }


private void FetchData_Q2()
    {
        ddlCardType.SelectedValue = "1";
        ddlProductType.SelectedValue = "1";
     }

but for both the side values are appearing as like as for second.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could post your code.

But as a suggestion, I would say add the dropdownlist in two different reapter controls, then populate the dropdownlist in the ItemDataBound event of the repeater control.

A better alternative would be to use jQuery like this in each td (or your panel):

```
for(var i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
 var options = $("#options");
 $.each(data, function() {
    options.append($("<option />").val(this.ID).text(this.Name));
 });
 //append the $("#options") to a parent div
}
```

where the data could be achieved by using Ajax GET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set selected value for dropdownlist, you have to change selectedindex. You can try something like:

```
private void FetchData()
{
    ddlCardType.SelectedIndex = ddlCardType.Items.IndexOf(ddlCardType.Items.FindByValue("2"));
    ddlProductType.SelectedIndex = ddlProductType.Items.IndexOf(ddlProductType.Items.FindByValue("5"));
}

private void FetchData_Q2()
{
    ddlCardType.SelectedIndex = ddlCardType.Items.IndexOf(ddlCardType.Items.FindByValue("1"));
    ddlProductType.SelectedIndex = ddlProductType.Items.IndexOf(ddlProductType.Items.FindByValue("1"));
}
```